# Why did my question's score suddenly decrease by $3$?

Tags: bug, score

I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838494/398708), "Show that $\int_0^{\pi/3}\arccos(2\sin^2 x-\cos x)\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi^2}{5}$".

Yesterday its score suddenly decreased from $25$ to $22$, and I wonder why. The question has $1$ downvote, given six days ago. Yesterday the question earned a "Good question" badge (score of $25$). After that I got a message, "$-10$ User removed".

It's of no importance; just curious.

Comment: Sometimes people who are acting maliciously also vote up good questions. I believe that when a user gets removed _all_ of their votes are revoked, so that would account for 10 rep points and one up vote going away. But 3 up votes disappearing? That's odd. Maaaaybe a person was running 3 different accounts got detected? But staff tends to keep pretty closed mouths about the details of account deletions, so you're unlikely to find out.

Comment: @JonathanZ Thanks. If one person was running three accounts, and then that person was removed, then I would guess that I should have received three messages that said "-10 User removed", but I only received one such message. Oh well.